# Debian: Screen stays black occasionally during boot with Asus P8Z68-V Pro/Gen3

Tags: debian, boot, x-server, radeon

I'm running Debian Wheezy on a Asus P8Z68-V Pro/Gen3 mainboard.
My graphics card is a Radeon 6850, I'm using the Open Source radeon drivers (xserver-xorg-video-radeon).

During boot, my screen occasionally stays black after boot menu selection. I cannot even switch to a terminal console. It freezes forever in that state.

Its really strange cause it only happens around half of the time and I cannot see any cause for this behavior. The other half of the times Debian boots successfully.

Answer (score 1):

The Asus P8Z68-V Pro/Gen3 mainboard has an onboard graphics adapter.

When I attached a screen to the onboard adapter (which I usally don't use), I noticed that the screen was actually not staying blank, but Debian used the internal graphics to display a boot error - even when I set "Initiate Graphic Adapter" to PCIE/PCI instead of iGPU (internal).

I get two different errors, which also seems to be kind of random. Mostly I get this error:

```
Loading, please wait...
INIT: version 2.88 booting
[info] Using makefile-style concurrent boot in runlevel S.
[ ok ] Starting the hotplug events dispatcher: udevd.
[ ok ] Synthesizing the initial hotplug events...done.
[....] Waiting for /dev to be fully populated...[    3.964436] usb-6-1.7: firmware: agent aborted loading ath3k-1fw (not found?)
[    3.964561] Bluetooth: Error loading firmware
```

And sometimes it already freezes at `Waiting for /dev to be fully populated`.

I tried to disable the onboard bluetooth adapter, but I still got the black screen error from time to time.

Next I saw that the Bios allows to run both internal and external graphics together - the related setting is `Advanced/System Agent Configuration/iGPU Multi-Monitor`. 
I disabled that setting. Now I don't get the blank screen error anymore.

Comment: I could not find a better place where to post this problem (and its solution), but I just wanted it to be somewhere on the net, maybe it helps some poor guy out there with a similar configuration. Should I post this on any mailing list or something similar - could this info be useful to some developers? If yes, where should I post this?

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked very well for me too. Approximately same setup but I'm using the properitary amd drivers.